# How to mass remove all friends updates in news feed in Facebook

Tags: facebook, news-feed

I just want to clean my Facebook news feed and start from crash adding my friends back.

What is the fastest way can I remove all friends from news feed?

Comment: delete account.

Comment: @MAKZ Are you serious?

Answer (score 1):

Officially, you have two possible courses of action:

1. Create a new account. Deleting your old one is not required, but would be recommended to prevent confusion.
2. Navigate to your friends list management page at `https://www.facebook.com/[your.username]/friends`. Hover over the *Friends* box and then choose **Unfriend**. Repeat until your list is clear.
   [image: unfriend everyone]

Unofficially, you could use a Greasemonkey script like [this one](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/162895).

**Disclaimer: I have not used this myself and cannot verify its effectiveness.**

Answer (score 0):

Search for any userscripts [here](http://userscripts.org/) and run it with Greasemonkey [Firefox] or Tampermonkey [Chrome]

Not sure if facebook timeline cleaner userscript still works, I tried using the script mentioned in [this](http://www.geekswipe.net/2013/11/delete-facebook-activity/) website and I think it may help you.